# How do I set the height of a Kendo Chart with the Server Side Wrappers for MVC?

Tags: kendo-ui

How can I set the height of the chart generated by the following code?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
.Name("Chart")
.Title("Wear")
.Series(series => { series.Column(new[]
                            {
                                measure1, measure2, measure3, measure4, measure5
                            }).Color("#585858"); })
.Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Format("{0}"))
 )
```

Answer (score 10):

Hello you can try to use the HtmlAttributes method to specify a style with the needed width.

e.g.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
   .HtmlAttributes(new {style="width:200px;"})
 //...
```

Comment: I will look into that.  FYI I am trying to set the height and not the width.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following;

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
   .Name("Chart")
   .Title("Wear")
   .Series(series => { series.Column(new[]
                      {
                       measure1, measure2, measure3, measure4, measure5
                      }).Color("#585858"); })
   .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Format("{0}"))

   .ChartArea(x => x.Height(350))
 )
```